# How to create the function for pandas rolling?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I'm now using python with pandas, and I would like to create the function to apply with the rolling method of pandas.

I want to create the rolling weight average for column rolling.

I've tried the code below, with the array of 'weight' is what I want to apply (The nearest value will have the highest impact)

```
from pandas.core.window import _Rolling_and_Expanding
def weighted_mean(df):
    weight = np.asarray([0.05,0.1,0.15,0.175,0.525])
    x = np.dot(df,weight)
    result = x/len(weight)
    return pd.Series(result, index=['weightedMean'])

_Rolling_and_Expanding.weighted_mean = weighted_mean
```

However, when apply to rolling function as

```
df['weightedMean'] = df.return_.rolling(5).weighted_mean()
```

It shown the error

```
----> 5     x = np.dot(df,weight)
      6     result = x/len(weight)
      7     return pd.Series(result, index=['weightedMean'])

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Rolling' and 'float'
```

Could anybody show me the way? Thanks a lot!!